# MVC - Dynamically bind database tables to var

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have inherited a badly designed database and have to convert the old code to MVC & EF.
I would like to be able to assign a database table name to a variable dynamically from within a SWITCH...CASE.
The table design is exactly the same, but there is a different table for different areas of the business!
How would I go about doing this? I am probably missing something extremely basic!
The code I currently have looks something like the following.

Declare the database

```
private CDBEntries db = new CDBEntries();
```

ActionResult Below

```
var cMembs = db.XXXcmembs;

switch (returnValue.ToUpper())
{
    case "CRI":
        cMembs = db.YYYsmembs;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
cSearchQuery = (from CCM in cMembs
                join CC in cDB on CCM.name equals CC.cname into CGroup
                from CC in CGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new CSearch()
                {
                    id = CCM.id,
                    Name = CCM.name,
                    Status = CCM.status,
                    cid = CC.id
                });
```

There are more joins in the live code, but for simplicity I have reduced the code to its basics.

Comment: I really do not get it, by Dynamically bind database tables to var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I have realised that what I want to do goes against the reason for using EF (i.e. compile time validation).
As all of the tables have the same layout I am going to 'merge' them into 1 table with an extra column to specify the area.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you will be able to use **var** like that. Var is strongly typed and declared at compile type.

[var (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var)

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type

You might be able to use **dynamic**, which is inferred at run-time.

[Walkthrough: Creating and Using Dynamic Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects)

> Dynamic objects expose members such as properties and methods at run time, instead of at compile time.

Let me know if you struggle, I will see if its possible from my side later today.